# Detect window visibility if inside cross domain iframe

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-domain

If a web page **A** is rendered in an `<iframe>` inside a *cross-domain* web page **B**, how to know when **A** is visible in **B**?

For example, if web page **A** is far below in the document scroll of **B** and the user has to scroll down to see it, how to know when the user has scrolled down enough to see the `<iframe>`.

[image]

There is only control/access to web page **A**.

Because of [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), there is no access to events or calculations to get this data.

[Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) only informs when a web page is browser tab active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) can be used to watch for changes on `HTMLElement` viewport visibility changes.

To check when the web page visibility, the `body` element is observed when at least 10% of its content is visible or not.

```js
const options = { threshold: 0.1 };
const callback = ([bodyElement]) => {
  if (bodyElement.isIntersecting) {
    // Element is visible.
  }
};
const observer = new window.IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

const bodyElement = document.querySelector('body');
observer.observe(bodyElement);
```

Check the specification for more information.

Keep in mind: It is not a standard API. So you might need fallbacks and it is not widely supported. Also, there might be performance concerns.